# Function/Algorithm that Returns Number of Roots within an Interval

Tags: functions, algorithms, roots

Let $f(x)$ be a (non-polynomial) function that is continuous and differentiable within an interval $[a,b]$ and has a finite amount of simple roots in that interval. Is there a function $g(a,b)$ or algorithm that will return the number of real roots in that interval? It will be sufficient for the algorithm to tell me if a root exists in that interval or not.

Comment: You have Sturm's algorithm – see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem).

Comment: @Bernard That is specifically for polynomials-- this function does not need to be a polynomial.

Comment: No, the set of differentiable functions is too large. Even if you restrict to compositions of trigonometric functions there is no algorithm to decide if the number of roots it zero or not.

Comment: The only way to know all the points that are zeros is to evaluate the function at every single point of the interval.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Is there any way to modify the argument principle to work with these functions?

Comment: Do you know the roots of the derivative in this interval?

Comment: @Andrei Yes, I do. Why?

Comment: When you have a problem, post the original problem.

Comment: Then it's trivial. Just compute the value of the function at those roots and at the ends of the interval. If all the values have the same sign, you have no root. Otherwise you have at least one

Comment: @Andrei Ahh... but that's a problem. When the interval is wide, I need to check a lot of points. I'm looking for a more efficient method.

Comment: @conditionalMethod What do you mean?

Comment: @WhoAmI Step 1, compare the first and last point. Then do it one root at the time. First time you change sign, you know you have a root. No need to look further. I assume that for a **particular problem** there might be more efficient ways to calculate this.

Comment: You have a problem at hand or which you don't know the answer. If instead of asking exactly that problem you 'model it' into some other version that you think if solved also solves your problem, then anything can happen. (1) There is no solution for the new version. (2) There are solutions but don't really solve your problem. (3) There are solutions, they also solve the original problem, but for the original problem there are better methods.

Comment: @Andrei Can you give an example? I don't think I follow.

Comment: Suppose $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$. The you have a root in that interval.If $f(b)<0$ and you don't have a root for the derivative, then the function is monotonic in that interval (either increasing or decreasing) and you don't have another root.

Comment: @Andrei Oh, ok. I was looking for something that could be generalized and be done efficiently (like the Argument Principle), but I guess that works. I don't want to check every point, though.

Comment: $f$ is only once differentiable?

Comment: @EricTowers No. I can modify it so it is differentiable to a arbitrary degree.

Comment: To use the argument principal you have to be able to guarantee you can pick a contour avoiding the poles and worse singularities, but you only have data about your function on the real line.  This is equivalent to trying to avoid the essential singularity of $\exp(-1/z^2)$ by extending continuously using only the data visible over the real line.  Using only real data, you can't know if there is a contour that avoids poles/singularities crowding against the real line.

Comment: @EricTowers So, there's no way.

Comment: Not without being able to restrict $f$ further.  For instance, is $f$ the restriction to the reals of a meromorphic function?

Comment: @EricTowers Well, $f$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere other than within $(-1,1)$.